# Why when opening a VS2013 project in VS2015 (Hebrew) text is seen as Gibberish?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2013, encoding, visual-studio-2015

I opened my project (C#, WPF) created in VS2013, in VS2015.
I have noticed that all of the text(written originally in Hebrew) is now in gibberish/rectangles .
This happened only when i rebuild the project.
Is there any reason for that to happen?

**UPDATE:**

I tried to change the encoding of the relevant files but it didn't help.
I tried with Notepad++ to change the encoding but i can't see it right(even in notepad++).
Is there any settings in VS2013 that is responsible to see the text in the right encoding?
Any idea what can i do?

Comment: Open original 2013 files in Notepad.   Notepad can saveas text files with different encoding.  Change encoding and save these text files with proper encoding in the vs2015 project.  I suspect the orignal VS2013 files were saved with wrong encoding, but didn't effect 2013 (encoding was ignored).  When project got converted to 2015 encoding was used when files are opened.

Comment: but there are at least 500 files, can't i change all the files in a global way? I've tried to write a code to change the encoding of all the files, and it did but i still can't see them correctly in vs2015. BTW i tried to opened the files with notepad++ and the encoding of the files was ANSI

Comment: Can you share what encoding was saved in versus what you need it changed to?

Comment: I would read files from one directory and then save results to a new file in 2nd folder.  Wouldn't try to save an existing file in a different encoding.  If you don't want to use a 2nd folder then read file, delete old file, and then create new file with same name.

Comment: tried all the above but got no change. is there a setting in VS2013 that is off in VS2015 that is responsible for this?